# Roles based Authentication is not working using asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles = "Admin" />
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**role is assigned**

```
 protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {      
                string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                string roles = string.Empty;
                bool check;
                using (RealEstateEntities db = new RealEstateEntities())
                {
                    check = db.Admins.Any(model => model.Roles == "Admin" && model.UserName == username);
                }
                if (check)
                    roles = "Admin";
                else
                    roles = "User";
               //  GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username,"Forms"), roles);
                Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Global.asax**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

**but it doesn't work **

```
[Authorize(Users = "Abid")]
```

**it Works when i change the roles to users in web config**
i am new to mvc4 plz help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asp.net MVC 4 you shouldn't use authorization in your web.config file (unless you want to protect custom folders).

You should register a global filter:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

and use `AllowAnonymous` when you do not want any kind of authorization for your action.

You can find a detailed explanation [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx), [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/thoughts-on-asp.net-mvc-authorization-and-security-/) and [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2013/06/authenticating-users-in-aspnet-mvc-4.aspx).

This [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/04/18/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous.aspx) shows you the differences between different asp.net versions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "you shouldn't use authorization in your web.config file" - how does this work with static content in the Content folder?

Comment: Good point. If you're using bundling you do not have to use the web.config otherwise you are right, you have to use it.